# scraping whole page source in c# windows application

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape page source but i found that in response whole page source not coming means some of the div values not coming though it is present in page view source but not coming in c# response.

Please guide me how to get those missing dive values in c# windows application.

Comment: Are those parts of the page generated by JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The elements that you're missing in the response might be elements added on the fly using JavaScript.

Assuming you're using HttpWebRequest to load the page, when doing that type of request, JavaScript won't get executed on the URL you're scraping.

Using WinForms, you could use a `WebBrowser` control which would allow you to load a web page, then on load completion, you could get the source of the page. I believe that would execute the JavaScript on the page.

Comment: I want to track url of "Copy Shortcut" link in google ig search result,
It present in page view source but not coming in c# response.
Please guide me how to track url of "Copy Shortcut" link

Answer (score 0):

You can Use below syntax where panel-header is ClassName of  HTML which we are using for identify our html portion.

```
var panelHeader = driver.FindElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By.ClassName("panel-header")).Text;
```

if you do not have classname or you want to use Id then you have to select

> By.Id("dash=1234")
>   this will fetch all text from the given class or id .